# OneNote 2010 Pen Thickness

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010, pen

Can you choose **any** pen thickness in OneNote 2010?

I think I remember being able to set a pen thickness in mm in OneNote 2007, but in OneNote 2010, the thickness selection is very limited.

Comment: I think this is a situation where "Microsoft knows best".

Answer (score 3):

Click Draw tab. You'll see two options for thickness and several for colors (under section Tools). On the very right side of this section, you'll see Up, Down and Down with line arrows. Hit the "Down with line" arrow (the last one) and then select "More Color and Thickness Options"

[image]

Comment: That still only gives me 9 options for thickness; I was looking for things thinner than the thinnest pen (0.25 mm) or thicker than the thickest pen (5 mm).

Comment: @JasonGross – I have reasons to believe 9 thickness options you mentioned is *all* what can be reachable through the user interface. If other thickness values existed, your access to them would need programming. (i.e. You'll have to extract XML representation of specific OneNote page and play with values stored there. Definitely not accessible from the user interface.)

Answer (score 1):

[Customize a pen](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/onenote-help/customize-a-pen-HP001119730.aspx):

> On the Standard toolbar, click the arrow next to Pen [image], and then, on the shortcut menu, click the
>   felt-tip pen or highlighter that you want to customize.
>
> Click the arrow next to the Pen button again, and then click Customize
>   Current Pen.
>
> In the Customize Current Pen dialog box, do any of the following:
>
> - In the Pen name box, type a new name for the current pen.
> - In the Pen color list, click a new color for the current pen.
> - In the Pen thickness (mm) list, enter a new stroke size (in
>     millimeters) for the current pen.

Comment: Please always include the relevant parts of your answer **here** instead of just linking to another site. Also, your link was broken. Check your post preview before you submit. Thanks!

Comment: This is for OneNote 2003 and question is about 2010. Where is "Standard toolbar" in 2010? You only have ribbons... This is not correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

I am required to use OneNote 2010 as part of my medical school curriculum, and was frustrated with my pen thickness options until I figured out a solution to this problem.

First, right-click anywhere in the Quick Access tool bar (located below File, Edit tabs)

Select "Customize Quick Access Tool Bar" option.

Under "Choose Commands From", click drop down menu and select "Popular Commands."

In window below, scroll down and select "Ink Styles". To the right of the window, click "Add."

"Ink Styles" should now appear in the window to the right. Click "OK" at bottom of window.

In the main screen of OneNote, click the "Ink Styles" icon (looks like three diff. colored pens) and hover over each of the pens under "Favorite Pens". When you hover, the pen thickness will appear in small grey box.

The thinnest pen size is 0.25 mm. To make it one of your accessible favorite pens (Numbered 1-8), right click the thinnest pen and click "move up."

Repeat above step until thin pen is at position #1. This is now "Favorite Pen 1".

Hope this helps!